# Android - How to get the currently "focused" object?

Tags: java, android, button, textview, onclicklistener

I want to let a `Button` identify which of my `TextViews` got the current focus. And after that the Button needs to apply changes to the focused `TextView`.

```
    TextView textView11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.frame1_1);

    textView11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView11.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            textView11.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            textView11.requestFocus();
        }
    });

    MaterialButton pb1 = (MaterialButton) findViewById(R.id.pin_button_1);
    pb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //1. get the focused textview or scan for the focused textView
            
            //2. apply button function to the focused textView

        }

    });
```

So how can i identify here

> //1. get the focused textview or scan for the focused textView

which `TextView` has the focus currently?
I think it might be possible with some `help variable` but maybe there os another way, because then i still need a `onClickListener` for each of the 22 `TextView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but should work

```
private TextView hasFocusTextView;
private View.OnFocusChangeListener onFocusChangedListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus)
            hasFocusTextView = (TextView) v;
    }
};
```

..

```
TextView textView11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.frame1_1);
//Use same listener on all textview you want to include with the focus logic
textView11.setOnFocusChangeListener(onFocusChangedListener); 

pb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            hasFocusTextView.setText("Changing text of the focused TextView");
        }

});
```

Comment: I added some some code into like `hasFocusTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA)` into the `onFocusChange` method, but there is no effect.

When I click a Button, I get a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply place these TextView in the same ViewGroup, then just traverse the ViewGroup's child views like this:

```kotlin
for (child in container.children){
    if (child.isFocused){
        //do your jobs here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use a variable to store which TextView currently has focus.

```
TextView currentTextView = null;

void initView() {
    TextView textView11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.frame1_1);

    textView11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            textView11.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            textView11.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            textView11.requestFocus();

            // Set the currentTextView to the currently focused
            // this must be used in every focusable textview
            currentTextView = (TextView) view;
        }
    });

    MaterialButton pb1 = (MaterialButton) findViewById(R.id.pin_button_1);
    pb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //1. get the focused textview or scan for the focused textView
            
            // focused textview is currentTextView

            //2. apply button function to the focused textView

            // Edit: Check for nullability
            if (currentTextView != null) {
                // use the variable currentTextView
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: This works, but it would result into a lot of duplicate code, right?

Comment: If the focused TextView is only used once, then you could check all the 22 TextViews inside the `Button`'s `onClick` (which could be achieved by putting them in a separate layout or another form of array). But, otherwise, the cleanest way is to just store the reference and use it when required.

Comment: @sagalo1 Since there are lots of `TexView`s, the alternative would require more code.
It's not really duplication (and, also, `currentTextView` should be checked for nullability before each use, see the edit in my post).